# How to center items on lists (ul li) in div class?

Tags: html, css, styles, html-lists, center

I'm trying to center a horizontal list of small icons. For anyone familiar with Launchrock, users are able to supposedly customize all the code. Note I cannot see any of their standard CSS, but we can override all their CSS.

```
<div class="LR-site-connect">
    <ul class="LR-connect-share-links LR-clearfix">
        <li><a href="#" class="LR-connect-icon connect-rss" title="rss"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="LR-connect-icon connect-github" title="github"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="LR-connect-icon connect-pinterest" title="pinterest"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="LR-connect-icon connect-youtube" title="youtube"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Launchrock (the popular service I'm using to build my landing page) doesn't allow us to see any of their CSS. We can only view their HTML. However, we can override their CSS. This is why this is so difficult...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your icons are 16px wide and you want the layout to be:

```
[      [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]      ]
```

You can try the following:

```
.LR-connect-share-links { width: 94px; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; }
.LR-connect-share-links > li { float: left; width: 16px; margin-right: 10px; }
.LR-connect-share-links > li:last-child { margin-right: 0; }
```

Add in some `!important`s to the properties that need to be overridden and you should have a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to override any css and stick that centered:

```
margin:0 auto !important;
```